# how to randomize image once it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a random gif generator. Very simple in design, just have the gif/img load in and once the user clicks/taps it randomizes and pulls another random image from the array.

For now I would just like to have the image randomize when it is clicked.

Currently it only randomizes when the page is refreshed.

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/rand.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<head>
    <title>Gif Generator - Prototype</title>
</head>

<body> 

    <h1>Gif Generator - Prototype</h1>

    <section> 
        <p>This image is random</p>
        <a href="#" class="click">
            <script>
                getRandomImage()
            </script>
        </a>
    </section>



</body>
```

JS

```
var randomImage = new Array();

randomImage[0] = "images/100.jpg";
randomImage[1] = "images/200.jpg";
randomImage[2] = "images/300.jpg";
randomImage[3] = "images/400.jpg";


function getRandomImage() { 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
document.write('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
}
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Based on the tags, I would say yes.

Answer (score 1):

As per your jQuery reference at the top, below is the proposed solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
        $(this).html('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great. Only issue i'm having is the click isn't activating 100% of the time. 
I find it's working maybe 35/40 of the clicks. Sometimes I will click and it won't change.

Comment: You can add a "currently selected" variable and do a while to make sure that the image does randomly change to something else than the current image.

Answer (score 0):

on click method serves the purpose.
in an `<img>` tag you can add an `onclick` method

```
<img src="" alt="Random image" onclick="getRandomImage()">
```